# Export sqljdbc4 as OSGi service

Tags: apache-camel, osgi, apache-karaf, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I'm trying to create a camel route using a sqlserver-database as an endpoint. I've come to understand that the common way of integrating data sources in OSGi is to export them as OSGi services.

For testing and development purposes I've used an H2 in-memory database and successfully exported it as a service. When I tried to do the same thing with SQL Server I ran into some problems however.

I downloaded the SQL Server JDBC driver and added the .jar to my local Maven repository as such:

```
$ mvn install:install-file -Dpath=<path-to-jar> 
    -DgroupId=com.microsoft.sqlserver -DartifactId=sqljdbc4 -Dversion=4.0.2206
    -Dpackaging=jar
```

I then proceeded to wrap the .jar in an osgi-bundle by creating a pom.xml like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
    <artifactId>sqljdbc4-osgi-bundle</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SQL Server JDBC Driver</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId> 
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version> 
                <extensions>true</extensions> 
                <configuration> 
                    <instructions> 
                        <Embed-Dependency>*</Embed-Dependency>
                        <_exportcontents>
                            com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.*
                            , microsoft.sql.*
                        </_exportcontents>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration> 
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.2206</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I was able to successfully install the bundle in Karaf so then I went ahead to create my service blueprint:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/1.0.0">
    <bean id="dataSource" class="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource">
        <property name="URL" value=<db-connectionString> />
        <property name="user" value=<username> />
        <property name="password" value=<pw> />
    </bean>
    <service id="dataSourceService" ref="dataSource" interface="javax.sql.DataSource">
        <service-properties>
            <entry key="osgi.jndi.service.name" value="jdbc/myDb" />
        </service-properties>
    </service>
</blueprint>
```

Now, when I copy the blueprint to /deploy nothing happens, no bundle gets installed and nothing in the log. When I did the same thing for the H2 data source a bundle was installed.

I'm using JBoss Fuse 6.2.1, camel-version 2.15.1 and Karaf 2.4.0

I would deeply appreciate any help on this matter.

Comment: Do you see the blueprint.xml as a bundle in karaf?

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, For the H2 data source, yes, but not the sql server one. I think I might have screwed up with wrapping the driver correctly but I'm not sure.

Comment: Try to install the original driver using the wrap:mvn: protocol

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, I tried that using "osgi:install -s wrap:mvn:com.microsoft.sqlserver/sqljdbc4/4.0.2206" and it showed up as a bundle but still nothing when copying my data source service to /deploy

Comment: You can try to put the blueprint.xml into a bundle and deploy it using install -s. This way karaf might give you some more informations.

Comment: @ChristianSchneider, Thank you for that suggestion, I did that and noticed that the bundle was in GracePeriod due to me missing the "v" in "/blueprint/v1.0.0" for the xmlns. Silly mistakes

Answer (score 1):

After getting it to work as is I propose you take a look at pax-jdbc.

https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Create+DataSource+from+config
https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/PAXJDBC/Pooling+and+XA+support+for+DataSourceFactory

It uses the DataSourceFactory from the OSGi specs to access databases in a universal way. There is also a karaf feature for adapting mssql called pax-jdbc-mssql.

Basically it allows to create a DataSource for mssql using just a config file. You do not have to create blueprint for it.